# Can I track ad revenue per each unique section of an app?

Tags: flutter, admob

To simplify, assume I've an app that's similar to Reddit and I would like to track the ad revenue for each subreddit.

In such case, what's the appropriate way to track the revenue for each unique subreddit?

I assumed that I could create an ad unit id for each subreddit but I'm not sure if that's appropriate or if it has any limitations (e.g. limit to how many ad unit ids can be generated). Please let me know If I'm misunderstanding how the ad unit ids work because all this is new to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**e.g. limit to how many ad unit ids can be generated**

-> There is no limit on number Ad units that can be used https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356431

You can have **n number** of ad unit ids used on single page as long as you follow admob implementation guidelines https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2936217?hl=en&ref_topic=9756841

**In such case, what's the appropriate way to track the revenue for each unique subreddit?**

1. Not sure which programming language you are using but you can use firebase analytics to track your ad revenue https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/measure-ad-revenue
2. Use Admob API to generate required report https://developers.google.com/admob/api
3. Or simply use apps.admob.com (**Reports->Start a new Report**) and generate report manually for each unique appid

Comment: Thank you.  I'm using Flutter and I'm also using Firebase for auth, storage, and analytics. Just to clarify, using the reddit analogy, I can create an ad unit for each subreddit once they are created and use that ad unit id whenever I'm showing ads within that subreddit? This way, using Firebase, I can see the revenue per each subreddit (e.g. ad unit id)?

Comment: @osaxma - yes. Just make sure to link your app to firebase https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6383165